# How to use the plugin Kaveri and Indus?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, program-slicing

From what I read [Indus](http://indus.projects.cs.ksu.edu) is a program slicer that identifies which parts of the program that influence or are influenced by a given set of program points, and [Kaveri](http://indus.projects.cs.ksu.edu/projects/kaveri.shtml) is a plugin that utilizes the Indus program slicing library to perform slicing in eclipse.

I downloaded a zip from this link http://forge.cis.ksu.edu/frs/?group_id=12  but I don't know how to use it. I want to know how to use this plugin?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [documentation](http://forge.cis.ksu.edu/docman/?group_id=12&view=listfile&dirid=35)?